# Connect to a local MySQL database in Intellij Ultimate without a server?

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea, localserver

I'm very new to Databases. I have to create a java program that interfaces with a MySQL database.

I created a database using MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE. I clicked on Local instance MySQL57, logged in and added the schema alongside the example sakila, sys and world schemas.

I then created a java project in Intellij that includes a reference to the Connector/J Jar (`mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar`). Then I use the following java code to connect to the database:

```
  try {
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "password";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Connected to Database");
 } catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

This works and I am able to use `connection.executeUpdate()` and `connection.executeQuery()` functions as necessary to perform SQL commands.

I want to be able to export my database schema and state so that somebody can import our database and then use our java application to connect to it as is.

I've added the database to the project locally in Intellij using `View|Tool Windows|Database` and then added a `Data Source| MySQL`and completing the wizard to connect to it. Do I need to start a server with Intellij or what do I need to do so I can give this program to somebody so that they can run it and use the accompanying database.

Essentially how do I make it so that my program has a database to store information that will work regardless of what IDE or Database server is running on some other persons machine?

Comment: want to be able to export my database schema and state so that somebody can import our database and then use our java application to connect to it as is. ? do you mean database or connection ?

Comment: If you can use executeUpdate/executeQuery you shouldn't need anything. The IDE essentially has nothing to do with the database. As long as the other person has mysql installed on his pc, he should be able to import your database dump. How that person connects to the database is up to the tools he/she wants to use. The connector should be sufficient if that person wants to connect via code.

Comment: My program uses the database to store information. So I need a way to ensure that the program, the database and the connection all work on someone else's computer. So I guess to answer your question both?

Comment: @MrRho How do I export the database from workbench? Is there a particular file format that I should use? This is my first MySQL project ...

Comment: @ryanmattscott, on the left hand side under management, there is a Data Export function (or also under the Server menu item). Just select the export to self contained file. It will export in plain sql statement format. The other person can then simply select the import function in the same place and load that file. Et voila. PS. You can also use the command line and the mysql client, but that is slightly more involved - the mysql workbench actually just executes this command in the background anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do anything to the program to 'make the database work' - you simply connect to the database from your application as per your code snippet. The database is a self-contained unit. Once you use the `executeUpdate/executeQuery` commands, you will simply change the **information** in the database.

The IDE really has nothing to do with the database - it simply provides a convenient interface to the database to view database information and allow editing of information / execution of queries - much in the same way the workbench does.

If you want to share your database with other people, you can simply use the Export database function (under the Server menu item) in the workbench or the `mysqldump` command line utility and export to a self-contained file. By default it exports the database and the optional information in said database to sql commands. This can then be imported on the other person's database as long as that person has the mysql server and client installed on his environment.

Comment: I noticed you also need to check the options Create Dump in a Single Transaction (self-contained file only) and the Include Create Schema option. Thanks for the tip got it to work on a friends computer